# MySQL master-slave after crash

Tags: mysql, replication, database-replication, master-slave

Here's the scenario:

1. I have one MySQL Master and 1 slave.
2. master-slave replication is set and works perfectly.
3. The slave machine crashes.
4. The master machine is still up and running.
5. Nothing changes in the master DB.
6. I start the slave machine again.
7. I start the slave MySQL DB.

Do I need to invoke "start slave" **again** on the slave DB ?

10x.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the slave will start automatically unless you have skip-slave-start in your my.cnf.

Run 'SHOW SLAVE STATUS' and see what it says.

Answer (score -1):

1. In master, check the status of the master and see it shows slave is running or not.
2. Goto slave machine and restart(stop & start) the slave machine.
3. Repeat the step 1 to check again